# Configure Spring Boot in external library

Tags: spring-boot

I'm currently code a library in Groovy and I want to use Spring Boot for configuration. That library has no main method.

I've succeeded to launch my unit test  by using Spring Boot with the code below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
class AddressTest { ... }
```

But I want to configure my Address class thanks the application.properties file. For a test, I've only wanted to change the log level while tests by inserting the line below in the application.properties file:

```
logging.level.root=WARN
```

But, that doesn't work.

I've tried add the @Configuration annotation in my test class or my tested class but the result is the same.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The first mistake you're making is using Spring Boot (or Spring Framework, for that matter) in a library, thus forcing your clients to use it too.